# How to implement fuzzy search in SQLite?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, fuzzy-search

I am trying to implement fuzzy search from SQLite database in my flask app but I am having some difficulties. I am using `sqlalchemy` for the database and the `fuzzywuzzy` package. The function I am specifically using is `fuzzywuzzy.fuzz.token_set_ratio()`. Is it possible to make a query that filters the records so it returns only those which when the above function is called with the user given string (from the search) and the name row from the table as arguments it returns values greater than 70 for example? I hope that made sense.

I tried this and I knew it would not work but decided to try it anyways:

`song.query.filter(fuzz.token_set_ratio(q, song.name) > 70)`

If such query is not possible to do, then how should I implement fuzzy searching in my web app?

Comment: SQLite has FTS5 virtual tables for fulltext search. It also supports using just about any Python function as UDF, so you could introduce `fuzz.token_set_ratio` as such and perform your query just as you envisioned.

Comment: Oops, I am sorry I did not see your comment. I managed to do it but thank for the help anyways!

Comment: Do post it as an answer then :)

Comment: I would but unfortunately when I post the code it exceeds the character limit. How can I share it as a comment in that case?

Comment: An answer should be posted as such, not as a comment.